# Find highest number of occurring values from col and replace the null with that value

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have table like below:

[image: table 1.1]

I want to replace the null values for tier_1 and tier_2 with the value with highest frequency of tier_1 and tier_2 resp. group by name.

something like below:

[image: highest occurring tier_1 and tier_2 for name A]

similarly had to find for other names B and C.
I tried with the below query, and it gives correct count:

```
select tier_1,name,max(tr_cnt) from (
select name,tier_1, count(tier_1) as tr_cnt from `my_table` group by tier_1,name having count(tier_1) >=1
)group by name,tier_1
```

the above code does work to an extent but then when i add tier_2 also in the query:
It says, ***Scalar subquery produced more than one element***

Is there a way to achieve this and replace the nulls with the max occurring value from that col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function to get the number of each `name` and `tier_x` combination and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to pick the `tier_x` that occurs the most:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(tier_1) OVER (PARTITION BY name, tier_1) counter1,
         COUNT(tier_2) OVER (PARTITION BY name, tier_2) counter2  
  FROM my_table
)
SELECT name,
       COALESCE(tier_1, FIRST_VALUE(tier_1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY counter1 DESC)) tier_1,
       COALESCE(tier_2, FIRST_VALUE(tier_2) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY counter2 DESC)) tier_2
FROM cte;
```

Note that in case of ties you will get an arbitrary value as the top `tier_x`.
If you want to break that tie you could use one more level of sorting in the `ORDER BY` clause of `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(tier_1) OVER (PARTITION BY name, tier_1) counter1,
         COUNT(tier_2) OVER (PARTITION BY name, tier_2) counter2  
  FROM my_table
)
SELECT name,
       COALESCE(tier_1, FIRST_VALUE(tier_1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY counter1 DESC, tier_1)) tier_1,
       COALESCE(tier_2, FIRST_VALUE(tier_2) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY counter2 DESC, tier_2)) tier_2
FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9f7ae77b90a48f6b066ce5488baa303).

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option (BigQuery)

```
select name, 
  ifnull(tier_1, max_tier_1) tier_1,
  ifnull(tier_2, max_tier_2) tier_2
from your_table t
left join (
  select name, 
    approx_top_sum(tier_1, if(tier_1 is null, 0, 1), 1)[offset(0)].value max_tier_1,
    approx_top_sum(tier_2, if(tier_2 is null, 0, 1), 1)[offset(0)].value max_tier_2
  from your_table 
  group by name
)
using (name)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note use of Approximate aggregate function [APPROX_TOP_SUM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_top_sum)

> Approximate aggregate functions are scalable in terms of memory usage and time, but produce approximate results instead of exact results. These functions typically require less memory than exact aggregation functions like COUNT(DISTINCT ...), but also introduce statistical uncertainty. This makes approximate aggregation appropriate for large data streams for which linear memory usage is impractical, as well as for data that is already approximate.